# add scroll tabs between some layouts

Tags: android

I want to add scrollable tab in an xml file. Normally I can add it like

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.scrollabletab.MainActivity" />
```

and it looks like:
[image]

but now I want to add this scroll tab at center of view. Center means above this scroll tab I have app logo, some layout which contains different textviews. and also I want to add some layout below this scroll tabs which again contains different textview and layout.

How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one widget: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

But common answer is: use Actionbar with Tabs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: Using ActionBar with Tabs we can add scrollable tabs at the top or at the bottom But I want to add it at center. Or there is any other solution for this except scrollable tab?

Comment: I think that above solution is the best for your purposes

Comment: thanks for your solution but I did not got you. Please see my original question I had added image to explain what I want to do.

Comment: I got it. You should review sources of that widget. Using PagerSlidingTabStrip you can put tabs anywhere in your xml layout. Overmore, that's really simple to customize it as you want

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a ScrollView within the layout that you use for your pager?